# Video thumbs that look like big pictures

Tags: video

Can anyone tell me how to do this with video files in windows 10 (please no registry edits)

[image: Please Halp -5th element XD]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Go to view and pick Large or Extra Large Icons as your Layout option.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, just before you go to extra large -you can briefly see some have the film border and others dont. Do you know how to make them all the same?

Comment: Ah I figure it's related to the aspect ratio

Comment: I have taken 2 videos one phone upright and one on the side (both 16:9) and the video taken upright displays like your example and the one on the side has the windows border.... Do you know how to fix this

Comment: Just figured it out!!! Thanks to this lead, thank you JMan Geek. - if theres any noobs like me out there . When your assigning artwork the image needs to be in profile not landscape (the image needs to be taller than it is wide but only just - this results in big beautiful thumbs :)